# Any way to disable the closing of apps?

Tags: x11, xorg, x-server

I have have a few apps that I don't want to be able to close. Is there any way to configure the `xserver` or anything else to achieve this?

The behavior I'd like to have is: click on closing x -> either nothing happens or the windows is minimized. (The x is the only way I would like to block.)

I'm using raspbian with xorg, lightdm & openbox.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us some context. Remember, we have no idea what you are trying to do. What operating system are you using? If Linux, which one? And what graphical environment? What desktop manager? We can't help you if you don't explain what you are using. And clicking on the 'X' is only one of the many ways you can close an application. Is that the only method you need to block?

Comment: That “closing x” is not managed by the X server, it's managed by the window manager. Some window managers let you specify that some buttons shouldn't appear on certain windows (or that they have a different effect, but if the button has no effect, you might as well hide it), but it's not a very common feature. What window manager are you using? If you're willing to change for the sake of this feature, what are you looking for in a window manager?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question, is there any info missing?
And I don't need anything specific but it should be as lightweight as possible, as I'm using it on a raspberry pi.

Comment: Is starting an app without the close button acceptable for you? If so have a look at the openbox documentation about per-application settings : http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Applications

Comment: @peyo yes that would be great, do you by chance have a list of the possible properties? The 'no close button' sadly wasn't an example on this site.

Comment: @Legatio so you don't want to make it impossible to close the application, all you want is to hide the X? The user can still right click on the title bar and select "close", they can still kill the app from the command line or using tools like `xkill`.

Comment: @terdon, correct, to disable the right click -> close would be a nice addition, but not really necessary. I would be fine with just hiding the x. I keep accidentally clicking it and have to reopen my apps.

Comment: If this is just for you, it might make more sense to simply move the x to the other side of the window from the other buttons.

Comment: I guess one could just do that. But I don't know how to do that either. Additionally others might come to this thread for a way to disable the closing of windows and this answer wouldn't help them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just remove the closing X icon is not a job for `x11` or the `xserver` but for the window-manager, in this case `openbox`. In the `/etc/xdg/openbox/rc.xml` or the `~/.config/openbox/rc.xml` is a tag called 'titleLayout'. The default value is 'NLIMC'. Here a list of what the characters mean from the [docs](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Configuration):

```
available characters are NDSLIMC, each can occur at most once.
N: window icon
L: window label (AKA title).
I: iconify
M: maximize
C: close
S: shade (roll up/down)
D: omnipresent (on all desktops).
```

So if you want to remove the closing X icon just remove the 'C' from the `titleLayout` tags value. The result would be 'NLIM'.

If you don't want to remove the icon but rather just move it to the other side you could write 'CNLIM'. Just move the 'C' to the other side of the string.